# Postgresql dump comparison across version

Tags: postgresql

I've been reading the multiple posts on dba.stackexchange and here on stack overflow about comparing postgresql dumps.  Those have worked well for comparing the same versions of postgresql dumps, but is there any good way to compare dumps across versions?  I wanted to check that the data moved from a 9.2 box over to a newer 9.4 box completed fully.

Thanks!

*Edit*

Hi Laurenz,  Ok, so here is an example of what makes me nervous. My understanding is that the auto-increment on these tables use these sequence numbers as the counter, but I don't get why they would be different even though the same number of rows are in both tables.

```
1005128c1005128
< SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.regqueue__rowid_seq', 917479, true);
---
> SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.regqueue__rowid_seq', 917491, true);
1238336c1238336
< SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.servicesstatuses__rowid_seq', 11767, true);
---
> SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.servicesstatuses__rowid_seq', 11791, true);
```

BTW, the database engine is the one I am required to implement, not one I have chosen. I'm still trying to learn it.

Comment: If there was no error message, everything was restored.

Comment: Laurenz, but that is leaving room for silent failure...

Comment: That would mean a bug in PostgreSQL. If you trust PostgreSQL little enough that you think it would silently fail to restore a dump, you should use a different database system. If you are paranoid, count the number of tables and the number of rows in the tables.